# Which are the files need on the system to compile and run java

Tags: java, makefile, jvm, javac, javacompiler

According to my understaning "Java Javac Libjvm.so are these 3 files are sufficient"

do libjli.so is also needed

Comment: The answer is no.  You need a full JDK installation.  If you try to cherry pick the files in an installation you will run into problems.  (And also, beware of what the Oracle license says you are permitted to do in terms of shipping their software embedded in something else.  Shipping a stripped down version of Oracle Java is strictly forbidden.)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  They are not sufficient. You need a full JDK installation.

If you try to cherry pick the files in a JDK installation, you will probably run into problems.

And also, beware of what the Oracle license says you are permitted to do in terms of shipping their software embedded in something else. Shipping a cut down version of Oracle Java is strictly forbidden by the old Oracle Binary License, and by the new OTN License.

If you are using OpenJDK, you are free to roll your own cut-down Java distribution.  But beware that if you embed components taken from the OpenJDK into your own product, your product needs to conform to the GNU GPL (+ Classpath extension) License terms.  For example, you need to make **your** source code available too.